# xdotool cannot find Qt application window, where wmctrl can

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gui-testing, xdotool

I want to detect a Qt5 QWidgets application from its 
window title using `xdotool` to test the GUI under GNU/Windows with the latest Xubuntu LTS distro.

When I create any minimal Qt application, with `wmctrl -l` I can detect it, 
with `xdotool` it cannot be found, as shown here:

[image]

(note that searching for `Enter s` also fails)

Does anybody have a good experience with using `xdotool` on Qt QWidget applications, 
without using tricks like `grep`ping through the `wmctrl` scripts?

AFAIKS, I am not [the only](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/xdotool-users/S8Re8JLTq8w) 
[one](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/xdotool-users/kz8DVVRXwr8) that has problems with this combination.

Comment: When you do "xwininfo" on that window, which name does it show?

Comment: @n.m. (I removed some info): xwininfo: Window id: 0x9600006 "Enter secret code".
Visual: 0x27.
Visual Class: TrueColor.
Border width: 0.
Class: InputOutputColormap: 0x9600001 (installed).
Bit Gravity State: ForgetGravity.
Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity.
Backing Store State: NotUseful.
Save Under State: no.
Map State: IsViewable.
Override Redirect State: no.

Comment: My question is not about obtaining the window ID using xwininfo (I do that now as a workaround). The question is about if this workaround is avoidable.

Comment: Does it succeed when you search for just 'Enter'? You may have a fancy space character there. Try `wmctrl -l | od -c' and see if there's something strange.

Comment: The space did not have an effect. But well, I have found an answer.

Comment: Post it then, for benefits of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I do not know which update caused this, but one day after the question, suddenly everything works as expected:

[image: Solved]

`xdotool` can detect Qt windows with spaces in its name as expected.